# How is form handling done in Reactjs

Tags: forms, api, validation, reactjs

Reactjs is quite new to me but I am able to create my components and load them in the view etc.

I am creating a form with react which I want to get data to bind from my api or sending data to my api.

Of course, I want some user validation on my input fields but I have red that validation usually isn't done by reactjs itself. Now my question is; should I interact with a library as jQuery for validation or with the api response given the input arrows and place them in the view if they occurred?

Thanks!

Comment: You should have frontend form validation and validation on your API. On the frontend a library like https://validatejs.org/ is good.

Answer (score 0):

You should always validate on server - even if you validate on client. That's rule we have to obey, amen.

Should you validate on client (React?). No, maybe, probably. Personal choice here.

I don't. I send data to server as is, validate there, process validation errors (if any) on client afterwards.

Why I don't?
- I don't like inline validation even before I submit form
- I don't like double work for one very same task (managing rules, syncing them across client and backend, ...), not to mention you have to handle error responses from server anyway.

Should you interact with jQuery? 
Despite it's possible, don't. Do it in React land, will save you from issues with keeping UI in sync, ...

Answer (score 0):

If you're using Redux, [redux-form](http://redux-form.com/6.5.0/) will offer you a great solution for form validation. It's a very simple and easy to use library.